# SUM amount field without commas, decimals, nor negative sign 11 digit leading zeros

Tags: mysql

Below select requires:

1. Dollar amount field 11 characters with leading zeros
2. No comma, decimal, nor negative sign
3. When leading zero, REPLACE decimal,comma, and negative sign is working I receive an error that varchar not used to SUM. When CAST as Numeric all the commas, decimals, and negative signs show.

`CASE WHEN psg_postingtransactions.[AMOUNT] != 0 THEN CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLICATE('0',12-LEN(RTRIM(psg_postingtransactions [AMOUNT])))+RTRIM(psg_postingtransactions.[AMOUNT]),'.',''), '-', '0') AS NUMERIC) ELSE '00000000000' END`

Comment: please give an example of an INPUT and what OUTPUT you'd like

Comment: Input would be 12345.67. The output would be 00001234567

Comment: Input would be 12345.67. The output would be 00001234567. If entering -12345.67 the result is still 00001234567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL try this:

```
LPAD(FLOOR(ABS(AMOUNT)*100),11,'0')
```

However your SQL looks like it is TSQL (MS SQL Server) and not MySQL see this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/47b813/1)

Assuming you do want it fo TSQL then, try this:

```
RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000000',CAST(ABS([AMOUNT])*100 AS INT)),11) AS LEADZERO
```

1. ABS() removes the minus
2. *100 will remove 2 decimals once result is cast to integer
3. CONCAT() places string of zeros in front of the integer
4. RIGHT(...,7) takes only 7 chars of the string we need for output

or, you can use floor() instead of the cast()

```
RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000000',floor(ABS([AMOUNT])*100)),11) AS LEADZERO
```

.

```
CREATE TABLE psg_postingtransactions
    ([AMOUNT] decimal(11,2))
;

INSERT INTO psg_postingtransactions
    ([AMOUNT])
VALUES
    (0),
    (123.45),
    (45678.1),
    (-12.56)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
   RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000000',cast(ABS([AMOUNT])*100 AS INT)),7) AS LEADZERO
FROM psg_postingtransactions
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/47b813/1/0)**:

```
|   LEADZERO   |
|--------------|
|  00000000000 |
|  00000012345 |
|  00004567810 |
|  00000001256 |
```

Comment: Not sure why but I prepared the sqlfiddle referenced above using length of 7 instead of 11. I amended the answer seen above but not the sqlfiddle.

Comment: Works great with SQL Server 2012. Do you have a suggestion for SQL Server 2008. I hope not to run into v2008 but sometimes the only machine of sql server I have to work on.

Comment: I think only the concat () is a problem for 2008, so try `RIGHT(('00000000000'+cast(floor(ABS([AMOUNT])*100)) as varchar),11) `
.